# error while upgrading ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg

Hi I tried to upgrade and I had the following result. Can you help me? Sorry I'm not very well versed in Ubuntu, so I hope I can follow your answers. Thank you!!

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.6) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.config: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (4.15.0-36.39) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (4.15.0-36.39) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Comment: Please add contents of `/etc/default/grub` to the question.

Comment: sorry, but how can I display the contents of /etc/default/grub ? Thank you!

Comment: Something like `cat /etc/default/grub` would be enough

Comment: @N0rbert thank you! I put it in my question (see above). Sorry for the cruel formatting, trying to change it

Answer (score 0):

I found the problematic line:

> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1""
> ```

You have two closing quotes.

Edit the line by removing last qoute:

> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
> ```

and then continue installation with `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: How can I do it? I deleted it, but that did not help...